# How do i delete the inner side of this shirt

Tags: selection-tools

How can i select only the inner side of the shirt and delete it so that i only have the outside faces of the shirt?

[image: shirt]

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is:

1. Limit selection to visible
2. Select all outside faces with C (do not select faces on the edge)
3. Change selection type from faces to vertices
4. Press ctrl-I to select the inverse (now you should have the inside selected)
5. Delete selected vertices

Comment: But what if i also want to delete the faces on the edge?

Comment: This will delete the faces on the edge